# How are these gitignore exclude-from-ignore subfolder patterns different?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a gitignore file that excludes a source directory, except for some specific files:

```
/src_app
!/src_app/Learning\ Module\-darwin\-x64/

!/src_app/assets/icons/mac/
```

The exclude-from-ignore the Learning Modules directory is the same regular expression as the one to exclude-from-ignore the icons directory, except I'm escaping the whitespaces in the Learning Modules directory, while the icons directory doesn't need that.

The weird thing is that all of the files under the Learning Module directory are being recognized, whereas no files under the icons directory are being picked up.

What is the difference between these two patterns that makes git recognize one sub-path while not the other?

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `src_app/assets` is *not being read at all* so that `src_app/assets/icons` is *never found*.  Not being found, it cannot be un-ignored so that it will be scanned to find `/src_app/assets/icons/mac` so that *this* can be un-ignored.

The fix is to first un-ignore `src_app/assets`, then also un-ignore `src_app/assets/icons`:

```
!src_app/assets/
!src_app/assets/icons/
```

The first of these makes Git look inside `src_app/assets` (so that it will find `icons`) and the second makes Git look inside `src_app/assets/icons` once it finds that.  The existing rules for `src_app/assets/icons/mac` will then take effect.

(If there are files within `src_app/assets/` and/or `src_app/assets/icons/` that should not be automatically added and should not be complained-about as untracked, you will have to list those as to-be-ignored.)

---

Side note: in `/src_app/Learning\ Module\-darwin\-x64/`, the backslashes before the hyphens are unnecessary (but harmless).  None of these are [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression); they are all [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

Comment: I wish I could vote this up twice, because I didn't understand the distinction of glob patterns -- I thought it was just slang, like blob.

Comment: It kind of is slang, but it's very specific slang. "Glob" is short for "global". Words that start as slang often become [jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon), as in this case. Jargon is important, but also a bit pernicious, as two people can use various words and think they are communicating, but aren't really because they're using the same word with different jargon-meanings.